# Using De Moivre's Theorem to prove things

Tags: complex-analysis

So I need to use ($\cos\theta$ + i$\sin\theta$)^4 to prove;

1) $\cos4\theta$ = 8$\cos^4\theta$ - 8$\cos^2\theta$ + 1

2) $\sin4\theta$ = 4$\sin\theta$$\cos\theta$ ($\cos^2\theta$ - $\sin^2\theta$)

The farthest I can get is equating;

$\cos4\theta$ = $\cos^4\theta$ - 6$\cos^2\theta$$\sin^2\theta$ + $\sin^4\theta$

and

$\sin4\theta$ = 4$\cos^3\theta$$\sin\theta$ - 4$\cos\theta$$\sin^3\theta$

How do it prove 1) and 2) from this? (assuming I didn't mess up my expansions and the equating)?

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there.

For $\cos4\theta$, use that $\sin^2\theta=1-\cos^2\theta$ and simplify.

For $\sin4\theta$, factor out $4\sin\theta \cos\theta$.